# Is there a reason workflow builders in F# don't use interfaces?

Tags: f#, monads

This is a question just out of curiosity: when you implement a workflow factory, you don't do it as an interface implementation, but rather just make sure the function signatures of the monad functions match. Is there a design reason for this?

Comment: My best guess is so that you don't have to implement all of it if you don't want to?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For one thing, the lack of higher-kinded types in .NET means that you can't give the methods useful signatures.  For instance, `ListBuilder.Return` should have type `'t -> 't list`, while `OptionBuilder.Return` should have type `'t -> 't option`.  There's no way to create an interface with a `Return` method that has a signature supporting both of these methods.

Answer (score 5):

I think that the lack of higher-kinded types as mentioned by kvb is probably the main reason. There are ways to workaround that, but that makes the code a bit obscure (see [this snippet](http://fssnip.net/3S)).

Another reason is that F# computation expressions allow you to define different combinations of methods. It's not always just `Bind` and `Return`. For example:

- Some define `Yield`, `YieldFrom`, `Combine` to allow generating results
- Some define `Return`, `ReturnFrom`, `Bind` to define a monad
- Some define `Return`, `ReturnFrom`, `Bind`, `Combine` to define a monad that can return multiple things
- Some also define `Delay` or `Delay` and `Run` to handle laziness

... so computation expressions would need to be defined as quite a few different interfaces. I think the current design leaves some nice flexibility in what features of computations you can support.

Comment: Yikes, much of that is really over my head! Yeah, I figured they'd need to make a ton of interfaces, but that didn't seem like a sufficient reason for a seemingly hackish way of allowing you to define monads.